# Function $f$ intersects with any line at most twice

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

> Function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ intersects with any line at most $n$ times, what is $f$?

Suppose that $n=1$, it seems obvious that $f$ is a line.

Suppose that $n=2$, it seems that sgn$(f'')$ must be a constant. For example, $x^{2k}$, $e^x$, $\ln(x)$.

My questions are:

1. How to classify all possible functions satisfying this condition?
2. What about the general $n=n$ case?

This is a function-equation problem. But only Math Overflow has a function-equation tag. So I added it here.

Comment: If $f$ is a line then it intersects with itself infinitely. That is more than $n$ times.

Comment: All polynomials of degree at most $n$ satisfy this property. However, there are non-polynomial functions satisfying this. For example, for $n=2$, all strictly convex functions do the job.

Comment: No function satisfies the condition when $n=1$, since any two points determine a line. When $n=2$, one shouldn't invoke $f''$ unless $f$ is assumed twice differentiable. Are we even assuming that $f$ is continuous?